# I want to create a custom taxonomy page showing a list of subcategories

Tags: categories, custom-post-type-archives

hoping one of you wizards can help me with this one. I'm fairly new to this. Here's the situation - I have a custom post type called 'Videos' where I set up a Custom Taxonomy called 'Country List'. I want to create a page like this https://www.vagabrothers.com/destinations that shows all the custom category titles and their featured images. I've no idea where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. The WordPress theme developer handbook is a good place to start. Especially the Loop (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) and the template files sections (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of your custom post type is "videos", you can create a new template file in the themes directory called `taxonomy-videos.php`. If your custom post type's permalinks are set up correctly this template will be rendered anytime the main query returns 'videos', so at 'http://www.yoursite.com/videos'.

In the template file you can start a loop and cycle through each post returned from the DB.